# Выбор чекбокса на сайте для python программы

Tags: python, requests

Вот уже несколько часов ломаю голову над тривиальной задачей.
По адресу https:// joblab.ru/access.php есть форма входа
Весь функционал для авторизации уже сделал, кроме переключения чекбокса.
Нужно, соответственно, чтобы при входе он был выбран

Везде, где нагуглил - предлагают делать это через селениум
Возможно ли сделать это без него? С помощью куки или заголовков
А если с ним, как корректно прописать путь?

На данный момент отправляю для авторизации:

```py
    data_ = {"type":"employer",
            "email":"email",
            "pass":"pass",
            "keystring": captcha,
            "submit":"1"
            }
```

Пробовал следующий код selenium:

```py
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
url = "https://joblab.ru/access.php"
browser.get(url)
browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*table[@class = 'tbl_padding table-to-div']/tbody/tr/td[1]/p/label[1]/input").click()
```

но он выдаёт ряд ошибок

В общем, основной вопрос, можно ли на конкретном сайте обойтись запросами и не прибегать к селениуму. И если да, то как?
Спасибо

Comment: Имеется ввиду чекбокс "запомнить меня"?

Comment: Посмотрите через инспектора браузера какой запрос отправляется с чекбоксом и повторите в запросе `requests`. А так, тот чекбокс скорее всего запоминается браузером (как и прочие теги input), или в localStorage (или его аналоге), может и в куках хранится. Все-равно, вам понадобится его отправлять в запросе

Comment: "Решил" проблему, менять верхний чекбокс оказалось необязательным. В итоге достаточно запроса и куки.
Оказалось, проблема в том, что используемый аккаунт заблокировали)

Спасибо тем, кто откликнулся